# Summarising and keeping the original values

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have the following tibble and want to replace the `NA` values with the sum of the "children" (e.g. the value for "c" is equal to the sum of "d" and "e". The value for "a" is then the sum of "b" and "c". So the problem is how to summarise and keep at the same time the original values.

```
mydata <- tibble(id = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 
                 value = c(NA, 1, NA, 2, 3),
                 parent = c(NA, "a", "a", "c", "c"), 
                 level = c(1,2,2,3,3))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
  id    value parent level
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
1 a        NA NA         1
2 b         1 a          2
3 c        NA a          2
4 d         2 c          3
5 e         3 c          3
```

Final result should be

```
  id    value parent level
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
1 a         6 NA         1
2 b         1 a          2
3 c         5 a          2
4 d         2 c          3
5 e         3 c          3
```

I have tried several approaches but the only one that work is lengthy and rather clumsy. I have the feeling there should be an easy solution in `tidyverse`. Any ideas ? (in a loop? the original problem has 5 levels).

Cheers

Renger

Comment: *"The value for "a" is then the sum of "b" and "c"."* Should the value for "a" be 1+5=6?

Comment: Yes. I added the expected result in my question

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `while()` loop to calculate `value` iteratively.

```r
library(dplyr)

mydata %>%
  mutate(value = {
    while(anyNA(value)) {
      sub_id <- id[is.na(value)]
      ind <- parent %in% sub_id
      value[is.na(value)] <- tapply(value[ind], parent[ind], sum)[sub_id]
    }
    value
  })

# # A tibble: 5 × 4
#   id    value parent level
#   <chr> <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
# 1 a         6 NA         1
# 2 b         1 a          2
# 3 c         5 a          2
# 4 d         2 c          3
# 5 e         3 c          3
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, that does the job.
Here is another example, that works using the trick by Maël

```
loop_level <- max(mydata$level) - 1
mydata0 <- mydata
for (i in 1:loop_level) {
  v <- with(mydata, tapply(value, parent, sum, na.rm = TRUE)) 
  mydata0$value <- dplyr::coalesce(mydata0$value, v[match(mydata0$id, names(v))])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please also try

```r
mydata %>% mutate(sum=sum(value), .by=level) %>% fill(sum, .direction = 'up') %>% 
mutate(value=ifelse(parent!='' & is.na(value), sum, value),
       sum2=sum(value), .by=level) %>% fill(sum2, .direction = 'up') %>% 
  mutate(value=ifelse(is.na(parent) & is.na(value), sum2, value)) %>% select(-c(sum,sum2))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  id    value parent level
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
1 a         6 <NA>       1
2 b         1 a          2
3 c         5 a          2
4 d         2 c          3
5 e         3 c          3
```